# Is there a numpy function to find an array in multi dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy array with  n row and p columns.

I want to check if a given row is in my array and find the index.

For exemple I have a numpy array like this :

```
[[1,0,8,7,2,2],[1,3,7,0,3,0],[1,7,1,0,1,0],[1,9,1,0,6,0],[1,8,1,7,9,0],....]
```

I want to check if this array [6,0,5,8,2,1] is in my numpy array or and where.

Is there a numpy function for that ?

I'm sorry for asking naive question but I'm quite confuse right now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `==` and [`.all(axis=1)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) to match entire rows, then use [`numpy.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to get the index:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,0,8,7,2,2],[1,3,7,0,3,0],[1,7,1,0,1,0],[1,9,1,0,6,0],[1,8,1,7,9,0], [6,0,5,8,2,1]])
b = np.array([6,0,5,8,2,1])

print(np.where((a==b).all(axis=1)))
```

Output:

```
(array([5], dtype=int32),)
```

Comment: I recommend to try and break up the expression to print each sub-part of it to understand the process better

Comment: thank you that the thing I was searching !!